# Showing irreducibility of polynomials of degree 3 over the rationals

Tags: modular-arithmetic, irreducible-polynomials

Let $\ g = X^3\ -9X + 16 $. Prove that $g$ is irreducible over the rational numbers.

So far I have used reduction modulo $5$ and this gives $g_5 = X^3 +X + 1$. Then I get
$$
g_5(0) \equiv 1 \pmod5,\\
g_5(1) \equiv 3 \pmod5,\\
g_5(2) \equiv 1 \pmod 5,\\
g_5(3) \equiv 1 \pmod 5,\\
g_5(4) \equiv 4 \pmod 5.$$

As none of these are equal to $0\pmod5$ does this mean that $g$ is irreducible?

Also would this work modulo $2$ or $3$? How do I know which prime to pick?

Comment: Yes, if $g_5$ does not have any roots $\pmod{5}$, then $g_5$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ since it has degree 3. Now use the $\pmod{p}$ irreducibility test to conclude that $g$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: So: Let $p$ be a prime an suppose that $g(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$ with $\deg g(x) \geq 1$. Let $g_1(x)$ be the polynomial in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$ obtained from $g(x)$ by reducing all the coefficients of $g(x)$ modulo $p$. If $g_1(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_p$ and $\deg g_1(x)=\deg f(x)$, then $g(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$